# Python - Datetime's Time is always zero

Tags: python, datetime, time

Strange little problem I'm facing with Datetime. Here's what I'm doing:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> t = date.timetuple(datetime.now())
>>> t
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=-1)
```

tm_hour, tm_min and tm_sec are all zero. Why is this?

Comment: I have tried exactly the same and all works fine for me

Comment: @Artsiom on my Ubuntu python 2.7.1 it doesn't work fine

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru - yep - you are right, i have tried in the several python interpreters and only one produce the same results for date.timetuple and datetime.timetuple. So guess it is something wrong with one of the mine python IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well `t` is a `date`, so of course it doesn't contain any time data. You have to use `datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())` to have those fields populated.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this in my console and get the following results:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

date.timetuple(datetime.now())
>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=-1)
datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())
>>> time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=13, tm_min=23, tm_sec=34, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=18, tm_min=25, tm_sec=20,  tm_wday=1, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.timetuple(datetime.now())
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=6, tm_mday=14, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=165, tm_isdst=-1)
```

this is my result.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
t = datetime.timetuple(datetime.now())
```